# Asymptotic Expansion of $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-z\sin^2(t)} \, dt$

Tags: asymptotics

I want to find the asymptotic expansion of $$\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-z\sin^2(t)} \, dt$$

As I need to find the entire asymptotic expansion (and not just the first term or two), it suggests I don't want to use Laplace's method (at least not on its own).

Which method would be most appropriate to use in this situation?

Additionally, as a rough idea, when is it best to use each technique?

Comment: Hint: Try the substitution $u = \sin^2 t$

Comment: Can you find a substitution such that you can apply the steepest descent method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the fact that

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm d}t~e^{-z\sin^2t}=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-z/2}I_0\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) \tag{1}
$$

with $I_0$ being the [modified Bessel function of of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions)

From this, obtaining an asymptotic behavior is straightforward, for instance, for large $z$ we have

$$
I_\alpha(z) = \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}}\left( 1 - \frac{4\alpha^2 - 1}{8z} + \frac{(4\alpha^2 - 1)(4\alpha^2 - 9)}{2!(8z)^2} - \cdots\right) \tag{2}
$$

So Eq. (1) becomes

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm d}t~ e^{-z\sin^2t} \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4z}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{4z}  + \frac{9}{32z^2} + \cdots \right)
$$